# Code snippets are breaking the wordpress image upload functionality, not sure what I did wrong with these 2 code snippets?

Tags: wordpress, function, code-snippets

The following 2 code snippets are breaking the image upload on my wordpress page showing the following error.

"An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later."

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

**CODE SNIPPET 1**

```
add_action('wp_logout','auto_redirect_after_logout');
function auto_redirect_after_logout(){
$url = 'https://www.website.com/home/';
wp_redirect($url);
exit();
}
```

**CODE SNIPPET 2**

```
add_action('wp', 'page_check');
function page_check() {
if (is_page('my-account')) {
if (!is_user_logged_in()){
wp_redirect( 'https://website.com/home' );
}}}
```

Comment: "CODE SNIPPET 2" has a syntax error: you have single quotes around add_action. If this was in your actual code then PHP would act funky around that statement.

Comment: btw, it should be: add_action('wp', 'page_check');

Comment: +1 for the syntax error pointed by @mattavatar but after correction on it, I don't have any issue to upload files when the 2 code snippets are running on my WP. Perhaps you have other plugins creating the bug? or was it just the syntax error???

Comment: @gael I love points... so, instead of commenting "+1", would you throw my comment an upvote?

Comment: @mattavatar, thanks for responding it was not a syntax error. That was a typo when I was writing up the question here.

Comment: @gael nope not syntax error, yes I think there could be other underlying issues, along side these 2 snippets.

Comment: How do you know that both code snippets are causing the problem?

Comment: @mattavatar, because when I deactivate them. the image upload works fine.

Comment: @mattavatar I already upvoted before to comment. But for the original Question, I didn't find any issue with the 2 code snippets and I guess the problem should come from a conflict with another plugin or theme. You could try to disable them with a plugin such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-safe-mode/ to test which one cause the conflict.

Comment: @gael good shout I will give that a go.